# Do I need to reinstall Windows 7 if I have an upgraded version of Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8-upgrade

Hi I'm trying to reinstall Windows 8 on my computer which was upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 8.

I've tried re-freshing and resetting the computer, but it seems to still have problems (everytime I boot up it says it's attempting repairs).

So I think I need to do a complete reinstall using the original disks.

Based on this question, it looks like I can use the ISO file that I originally got to boot up from a USB drive.
([Reinstalling upgraded Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/580852/reinstalling-upgraded-windows-8)). I'm just wondering, since it's an upgrade version does that mean though that I have to reinstall Windows 7 first before installing Windows 8 with this ISO file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sadly, yes.

You must have Windows XP SP3, Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8 Consumer Preview, or Windows 8 Release Preview.

Source: [Windows 8 upgrade's system requirements](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/buy)

> To install the Windows 8 or Windows 8 Pro upgrade, your PC must be running Windows XP SP3, Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8 Consumer Preview, or Windows 8 Release Preview.

Comment: Well that sucks. I just found out that I have access to Windows 8.1 with my msdn subscription. It's probably easier to just do a complete install into windows 8.1 instead then.

Comment: Yeah, agreed. I've always disliked upgrade-only installations :\